# React Native AIDL Missing

Tags: android, gradle, react-native

I'm newbie with react native, i already install node.js, Java 8, and Android Studio 3 with it's sdk and tools

I'm stuck on running React Native on my emulator :

```
react-native run-android
```

It's showing error like this:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugAidl'.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: aidl is missing
```

I already trying to download Android Marshmallow (23) and build tool version 23 too, changing gradle version, but it's not fix my error.

My build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
    }
}
```

gradle-wrapper.properties

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip
```

Full error message :

```
Starting JS server...
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && gradlew.bat installDebug)...
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)
The JavaCompile.setDependencyCacheDir() method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 4.0.
Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
The TaskInputs.source(Object) method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 4.0. Please use TaskInputs.file(Object).skipWhenEmpty() instead.
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72301Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42301Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComFacebookFbuiTextlayoutbuilderTextlayoutbuilder100Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComFacebookFrescoDrawee130Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComFacebookFrescoFbcore130Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComFacebookFrescoFresco130Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComFacebookFrescoImagepipeline130Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComFacebookFrescoImagepipelineBase130Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComFacebookFrescoImagepipelineOkhttp3130Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComFacebookReactReactNative0504Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComFacebookSoloaderSoloader010Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareOrgWebkitAndroidJscR174650Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugAidl'.
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: aidl is missing

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 46.33 secs
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-setup.html
```

What am i missing? how to fix it?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I got this error in Android studio's Event Log when I open the android project.

> Instant Run requires a newer Android Gradle Plugin. Update to 3.0.1.
>                 (Don't show again)

Then, I click "Update to 3.0.1" and the error is gone. Hope this helps.